# Helpers to create custom classes, macros and styles for LaTeX

Tags: linux, latex

To create and compile my [**LaTeX**](http://www.latex-project.org/) stuff, I am currently working with [**TexMaker**](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) on [**Ubuntu**](http://www.ubuntu.com/). TexMaker has many options and wizards, but what I’m dearly missing is something that enables me to easily create templates/classes with custom macros and custom styles.

I would have been more than happy if I would have found a full-fledged WYSIWYG template editor that creates classes and styles (CLS & STY files) for me, but after searching the internet for several months, that seems to be too much to ask… which leaves me with the hope that smart people at least created helpers to create custom macros and custom styles so I can create my own template classes and styles.

Which LaTeX “helper” tool(s) can help me create custom macros and styles via "wizard"-alike functions? Can you point me to any ***template editors*** and/or ***wizards*** that help me create my own ***classes*** and ***styles*** (**CLS** & **STY** files) – preferably, but not necessarily, in a WYSIWYG way.

Maybe I‘ve got it wrong, but to me CLS and STY files are somewhat like what templates and CSS are for a website… I mean, class files implement the specific structure of the document, whereas packages are used (to provide either generic functionality to any document, or) to ‘style’ the methods provided by a specific class. Related examples of what I mean are available at sites like (eg) [latextemplates](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/custom-class) and co. So, I’m practically asking for tools and/or wizards that can help me create those (in part or – in a best case – completely).

Of course it would be nice if it’s [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) and [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source) too, but it doesn’t have to be.

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing, but if it existed, I would have thought the folks at tex.sx would have heard of it. Did you check with them about asking it there. I don't think TeX is the kind of thing that lends itself to "wizards".

Comment: Also, have you looked at [Memoir](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) and [Koma-script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script?lang=en)? These are pretty versatile classes which can be configured by setting a few parameters, unlike the rather basic default classes that require a lot of packages to change the visual appearance.

Comment: Seconding Gilles' recommendation for Memoir - I typeset my dissertation with it, and was very pleased with the customizability! It comes with a great [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf) that itself is a great -if somewhat extensive ;)- example of the class' usage!

Comment: Lyx is the best WYSIWYG editor for LaTeX that I have found, but it doesn't do these template/class editing things you want, I'm not sure anything does.